# Contoller script doesn't change direction when the character looks around

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a controller script from the official Unity website to move my character around. I'm also using a script to turn the camera using the mouse. Everything works fine until the character looks around and faces a different direction. Then the WASD controls move them according to the original orientation. For example, if I turn 180 degrees W moves me backward and S moves me forward.

I've tried to figure this out using transform.forward but I don't really know what I'm doing.

The movement script:

```
CharacterController characterController;

public float speed = 6.0f;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
public float gravity = 20.0f;

private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

void Start()
{
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (characterController.isGrounded)
    {
        // We are grounded, so recalculate
        // move direction directly from axes

        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection *= speed;

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    }

    // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
    // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
    // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move the controller
    characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Transform.TransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html) to convert from local direction to world direction. Call that with the local direction you want to move and it will return the corresponding world direction which you can give to `CharacterController.Move`:

```
void Update()
{
    if (characterController.isGrounded)
    {
        // We are grounded, so recalculate
        // move direction directly from axes

        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection = moveDirection * speed;

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    }

    // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
    // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
    // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;


    // Move the controller
    characterController.Move(worldMoveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

In fact, the old documentation for [`CharacterController.Move`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) used this very method!

> ```
> void Update()
> {
>     if (controller.isGrounded)
>     {
>         // We are grounded, so recalculate
>         // move direction directly from axes
>
>         moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
>         moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
>         moveDirection = moveDirection * speed;
>
>         if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
>         {
>             moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Apply gravity
>     moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y - (gravity * Time.deltaTime);
>
>     // Move the controller
>     controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I's because `Move` uses world space coordinates but you generating local.

Try change

```
  moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
```

to

```
  moveDirection = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```